# Thread printing extra lines in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running a program with threads, sleeping them for a random amount of time and then waking them up. When it reaches the end, it prints that the last thread is now awake 6 different times. It does not do this on any of the other ones. Does anyone know why it is doing this?

sampleThread.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class sampleThread extends Thread{
    sampleThread thread;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public void run() {

        thread = new sampleThread();
        int randSleep = rand.nextInt(1000);

        System.out.println(thread.getName() + " is sleeping for " + randSleep + " milliseconds");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(randSleep);
            System.out.println(thread.getName() + " is NOW AWAKE");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

driver.java

```
public class driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {


        List<Future<?>> futArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);

        sampleThread temp = new sampleThread();
        for (int i=0; i<120; i++) {
            Future<?> future = es.submit(temp);
            futArray.add(future);
        }
```

output:

```
Thread-117 is sleeping for 547 milliseconds
Thread-117 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-118 is sleeping for 442 milliseconds
Thread-118 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-119 is sleeping for 182 milliseconds
Thread-119 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-120 is sleeping for 487 milliseconds
Thread-120 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-120 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-120 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-120 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-120 is NOW AWAKE
Thread-120 is NOW AWAKE
```

I expected it to just run through and print when each was sleeping and done. Instead, it prints the last thread several times.

**EDIT**:

If anyone was wondering, I changed

```
public class sampleThread extends Thread{
sampleThread thread;
Random rand = new Random();

public void run() {

    thread = new sampleThread();
```

Instead of putting `sampleThread thread;` outside of run() and `thread = new sampleThread();` inside of run(), I simply combined them into one statement of `sampleThread thread = new sampleThread();` and put the whole line into run. This seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Good first question! Thanks for following the requirements and posting a [mcve].

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you so much! I really appreciate all your help. Additionally, I took your advice and deleted my answer and posted it as an edit to my original question.

Comment: Excellent, be sure to take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask] as well (although you seem to have gotten the gist of that already) to get familiar with how we operate.  Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are duplicating effort. The fact that you had 120 threads should have been a hint.  You created a thread pool but then ran code that created an *extra* thread on each submission.

Simple solution:

1. Don't extend `Thread`, implement `Runnable`, that's all you need.
2. To get the thread name use `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

Like so:

```
public static class sampleThread implements Runnable {
     Random rand = new Random();

    public void run() {

         int randSleep = rand.nextInt(1000);

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is sleeping for " + randSleep + " milliseconds");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(randSleep);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is NOW AWAKE");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Now the output is

```
pool-1-thread-1 is sleeping for 526 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-6 is sleeping for 497 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-4 is sleeping for 565 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-5 is sleeping for 978 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-2 is sleeping for 917 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-3 is sleeping for 641 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-6 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-6 is sleeping for 847 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-1 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-1 is sleeping for 125 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-4 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-4 is sleeping for 884 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-3 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-3 is sleeping for 245 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-1 is NOW AWAKE
.
.
.
pool-1-thread-3 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-3 is sleeping for 863 milliseconds
pool-1-thread-5 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-6 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-4 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-1 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-2 is NOW AWAKE
pool-1-thread-3 is NOW AWAKE
```

Showing that you used only the 6 threads you ordered.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean about duplicating. Is there a major difference in extending thread as opposed to implementing runnable? Anyone I have ever learned from has always just said to extend the thread class, but provide no real explanation as to why they say to do that over runnable.

Comment: With thread pools, you don't need to worry about creating and managing threads, so everything should be a `Runnable`.  You will almost never need to extend `Thread` any more.